# See all users authorized in the report server?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Do I see all users who are authorized in the report host?, I want to see all the authorized persons of all reports in our report server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSRS objects (folders/datasources/reports) be default inherit permissions. However each object and all child objects can be set separate from their parent meaning there is not a centralized location to see this. You can create a report for this.

```
SELECT
    [Catalog].[Name]
    ,[Users].[UserName]
    ,[Catalog].[Path]
    ,[Catalog].[Description]
FROM [ReportServer].[dbo].[Catalog] WITH (NOLOCK)
JOIN [ReportServer].[dbo].[PolicyUserRole] WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON [Catalog].[PolicyID] = [PolicyUserRole].[PolicyID]
JOIN [ReportServer].[dbo].[Users] WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON [PolicyUserRole].[UserID] = [Users].[UserID]
WHERE
    [Catalog].[Type] = 2    --Reports
ORDER BY
    [Catalog].[Name]
    ,[Users].[UserName]
```